# Return data from same table in two columns filtered by WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in the table SALES:

```
Customer   Year   Amount'
 1         2011     1500
 1         2012     2000
 1         2013     1900
 2         2011     4500
 2         2012     5000
 2         2013     6000
```

By using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM SALES WHERE Year=2012 
UNION
SELECT * FROM SALES WHERE Year=2013
```

I get this result:

```
Customer  Year  Amount
1         2012  2000
1         2013  1900
2         2012  5000
2         2013  6000
```

But, now my question: How should I write my query to get a result presented as the following?

```
Customer  Amount2012 Amount2013
1         2000        1900
2         5000        6000
```

Comment: See this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `UNION` in order to write two conditions, you can do this using the `IN` predicate or `WHERE Year = 2012 OR Year = 2013`, then use the `CASE` expression to put the amounts for each year in a separate column:

```
SELECT
  Customer,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Year = 2012 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Amount2012,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Year = 2013 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Amount2013
FROM SALES 
WHERE Year IN(2012, 2013)
GROUP BY Customer;
```

---

Or, you can use the [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator to pivot the rows of the amounts into columns, something like this:

```
SELECT
  Customer,
  [2012] AS Amount2012,
  [2013] AS Amount2013
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM Sales 
  WHERE Year IN(2012, 2013)
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Amount)
  FOR Year IN([2012], [2013])
) AS p;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d012/4)

This will give you:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ CUSTOMER  ║ AMOUNT2012  ║ AMOUNT2013 ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║        1  ║       2000  ║       1900 ║
║        2  ║       5000  ║       6000 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Customer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Year=2012 then Amount else 0 END) Amoumt2012,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Year=2013 then Amount else 0 END) Amoumt2013
FROM SALES WHERE Year in (2012 ,2013)
GROUP BY Customer
```